# How can i control the position to copy one sheet into another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have code to copy one worksheet of original workbook to terminated workbook and it works fine. But i need control the paste position to terminated workbook. Right now it paste before what ever the active sheet. I want to it be past into the second sheet after my summary sheet. I am very new to Macro, thanks.

```
Sub CopytoTernimal()
Dim CopyName As String

On Error GoTo ErrMess

CopyName = InputBox("Please enter the name of sheet which will copy to ternimal")

Dim thisSheet As Worksheet

Set thisSheet = Workbooks("original.xlsm").Worksheets(CopyName)

thisSheet.Rows.Copy

Dim NewSheet As Worksheet
Set NewSheet = Workbooks("Terminated Employees.xlsm").Worksheets.Add()
NewSheet.Name = thisSheet.Name
NewSheet.Paste

thisSheet.Delete
```

ErrExit:
   Exit Sub

ErrMess: MsgBox "xxxxxx." 
  GoTo ErrExit

```
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it would be something like

```
thisSheet.Copy After:=Workbooks("Terminated Employees.xlsm").Worksheets("name of the first summary worksheet")
```